# Impossible to show differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have been thinking about this for quite a while, but I just don't see how to show that the function $$f(x_1,...,x_n) = \frac{1-e^{-1}e^{-\frac{a^2}{||x||_2^2 - a^2}}}{1- \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos(x_i)}{n}}$$ is infinitely often differentiable in zero.

I checked by plotting this function that this is actually true, but proving this seems to be impossible hard, as I don't see a systematic way of approaching this problem.

Comment: That looks messy....  :(

Comment: Do you take $a\neq0$?

Comment: yes, $a \neq 0.$

Comment: And $n>1$?${}{}$

Comment: actually, I need it for $n \ge 3.$

Comment: Ok. How did you find this function? Are there equivalent ways to express it?